# I want to parse a string as HTML inside a data attribute with AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm using ngSanitize to parse the var:

```
var icon = $sce.trustAsHtml('&#x020;');
```

but, I can't use `ng-bind-html` or `ng-bind-html-unsafe` in the view as I am trying to add the value to a data tag:

```
<i class="icon" data-icon="{{ message.icon }}"></i>
```

Results in:

```
<i class="icon" data-icon="&#x020;"></i>
```

I also tried:

```
<i class="icon" ng-attr-data-icon="message.icon"></i>
```

Also didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What do you get when you do this?

```
var icon = $sce.trustAsHtml('&#x020;');
console.log(icon);
$scope.message = icon;
```

---

How about instead of

```
var icon = $sce.trustAsHtml('&#x020;');
```

you do:

```
$scope.someUniqueIconName = $sce.trustAsHtml('&#x020;');
```

Then in your html do:

```
<i class="icon" data-icon="{{someUniqueIconName}}"></i> or
<i class="icon" ng-attr-data-icon="someUniqueIconName"></i>
```